# UITableViewCell loading Custom XIB for different Orientation and Cell Types

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom cell class named `ProductiPadCell`, designed for iPad. (iOS 5 SDK)

What I am trying to achieve is to load my custom cell according to the current state (expanded or not) and interface orientation. I am handling both condition within the view controller, the problem is I don't like the performance of it. I have **NOT** defined a cellIdentifier for any of the xibs defined below, and recently I detected that my `tableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

`ProductiPadCell` have 4 different XIBs which are;

```
ProductiPadCell-Regular.xib
ProductiPadCell-Regular-Landscape.xib
ProductiPadCell-Expanded.xib
ProductiPadCell-Expanded-Landscape.xib
```

ProductiPadCell defition;

```
@interface ProductiPadCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *detailButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productDescriptionLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel *timeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel *def1Label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel *def2Label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnail;
    // appears in case the cell is expanded
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *detailHolderView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;
// calls a method at the superview's ViewController
- (void)presentDetailViewWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
@end
```

TableView's cellForForAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // table identifier does not matches the xib's cell identifier
    // cell identifier of all 4 xibs are "" (empty)

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BOOL isExpanded = [[[targetDictionary objectForKey:@"isItemExpanded"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    ProductiPadCell *cell = (ProductiPadCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        // Load the required nib for the current orientation and detail selection style
        if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
            if (isExpanded) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductiPadCell-Regular-Expanded" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                // additional settings for expanded case
            }
            else {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductiPadCell-Regular" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                // additional settings for NOT expanded case                    
            }   
        }
        else {     
            if (isExpanded) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductiPadCell-Landscape-Expanded" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            else {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductiPadCell-Regular-Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
        }
    }

    // connect cell information with cell IBOutlets
    cell.productDescriptionLabel.text = [[targetDictionary objectForKey:@"key"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // ....

    [cell.thumbnail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_image.jpg"]];
    [cell.thumbnail.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [cell.thumbnail.layer setBorderWidth:5.0f];
    [cell.thumbnail.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [cell.thumbnail setClipsToBounds:YES];

    if (isExpanded) {
        cell.detailLabel.text = [[targetDictionary objectForKey:@"key"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

What should I do in order to load my xib's, other than my current approach? In every orientation change and button click, I call `[tableView reloadData]` and since `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier` does not find the simpleTableIdentifier it always creates new cells. If I define the `simpleIdentifier` to my cell xibs, they are not changing during case changes (orientation change, expand state change).

What is the best use of cell identifiers? Should I be using another approach other than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier`

I am waiting for any sort of solution to my current situation, because I am sure loading every cell over and over again is not the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, cache nib

synthesize this property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id cellNib;

@synthesize cellNib = _cellNib;
```

Make custom getter

```
-(id)cellNib
{
    if (!_cellNib) 
    {
        Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UINib");
        if ([cls respondsToSelector:@selector(nibWithNibName:bundle:)]) 
        {
            _cellNib = [[cls nibWithNibName:@"SomeCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] retain];
        }
    }

    return _cellNib;
}
```

in **viewDidLoad**

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SomeCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentification];
```

in **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
SomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentification];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        //If nib cache
        if ([self cellNib]) {
            NSArray* viewFromNib = [[self cellNib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
            cell = (SomeCell *)[viewFromNib objectAtIndex:0];
        }else { //nib not cache
            NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeCell" owner:nil options:nil];
            cell = (SomeCell *)[views objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: just to make sure I understand it correctly, I just have 4 different cellNib for my case, where each of them have different identifiers and register all 4 of my nibs in the viewDidLoad (like you indicated) After that I check which nib I need in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: with that identifier ? This is the first time I am seeing registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: and its not commonly used. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new method, registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: to register your nibs. You do this once for each nib, in viewDidLoad is a good place. The cell in each nib should have a reuse identifier, which you use to register the nib, and also in cellForRowAtIndexPath when you dequeue. The new method to use in cellForRowAtIndexPath is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:. Use that method, and there is no need to have the if (cell == nil) clause, the system will create one from the nib if necessary.